# Java string producing error when converting to an int

Tags: java, string, parsing, int

I am trying to use Integer.parseInt() to convert a string representing a phonenumber into an int I can use.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Enter a 10-digit telephone number with optional space or dash after the first and the second block of three digits >
5558759142
Processing encrypted number "5558759142"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5558759142"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at TelephoneNumberValidator.main(TelephoneNumberValidator.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Integer;

public class TelephoneNumberValidator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String VALID_PHONE_PATTERN = "[0-9]{3}[-| ]?[0-9]{3}[-| ]?[0-9]{4}";
        final int NUMBERS_FOLLOWING_AREA_CODE = 7;
        final int DECRYPTED_AREA_CODE = 212;
        Scanner scanKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;

        do {
            System.out.println( "Enter a 10-digit telephone number with optional space or dash after the first and the second block of three digits >" );
            userInput = scanKeyboard.nextLine();
            //check to see if the phone number is correct
            if ( !userInput.matches(VALID_PHONE_PATTERN) )
            {
                System.out.println("The given input \" " + userInput + " \" is not valid");
            }
        }while ( !userInput.matches(VALID_PHONE_PATTERN) );

        //extract int from string
        String phoneJustNumbers = userInput;
        phoneJustNumbers = phoneJustNumbers.replaceAll("-",""); // replaces hyphens
        phoneJustNumbers = phoneJustNumbers.replaceAll(" ", "");

        System.out.println( "Processing encrypted number \"" + phoneJustNumbers + "\"" );
        //check the first 3 digits (aka area code) to see if it matches 212
        int areaCode =  Integer.parseInt(phoneJustNumbers);//gets area code
        int placeholderForAreaCode = 111; //set 111 so that each number in area code can be accounted for
        int placeholderForEntirePhoneNum = 1111111111; //set each digit to 1 so we can shift later
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
        {
            if ( (areaCode + ( placeholderForAreaCode * j ) == DECRYPTED_AREA_CODE ) ) // we are shifting each digit by one
                                                                                        // to see if it matches the decrypted area code
            {
                System.out.println("The telephone number is \"" + ( Integer.parseInt(phoneJustNumbers) * placeholderForEntirePhoneNum * j )
                        + "\" with a shift value of " + j);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("The telephone number \"" + userInput + "\" cannot be decrypted area code." );
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So when I try to just substitute a hardcoded string it works using Integer.parseInt(). This leads me to believe the way I am generating cleaning up my string somehow stops this from working.
I am new to java so I don't know why that would be or what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The largest value `int` can be is 2,147,483,647. (See [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE).) Your example phone number is much larger than that. Try using `Long.parseLong()` instead, as the largest value for a `long` is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: Yes this was the issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Out of range. The largest number you can fit into int simple does not fit that 5 billion value your number represents.

Try long instead.

Or, better: use a specific class to represent phone numbers, for example by using an array only containing the digits of that number,but also keeping the complete initial string you got from the user for example.

Thing is : the fact that phone numbers contain numbers doesn't imply that a phone number should be stored as real number!

Comment: Yes this was the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Then just go forward and accept the answer you consider being helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

The input is exceeding the maximum that an Integer can accommodate (store). Change the datatype to long to get over this.

Seems too much of Integer Operations - maybe create a Telephone class, have the prefix etc., as separate fields/attributes and then act on them. Maybe usage of String would be better unless you need to do some mathematical operations,  converting is not advisable